# Hoare logic provide a proof or counterexample

Tags: logic

I came across a question ask to provide a tableaux proof:
$\{x>1\} a=1; y=x; y=y-a \{y>0 \wedge x>y\}$

I think it is false but I cannot think of an counterexample of it.

Comment: wont the fact that y=x and x>y close the tree in just one line?

Comment: Can you please explain your notation?

Comment: @bram The notation is standard.I'm sure the Wikipedia article on Hoare logic explains it.

Comment: It looks true to me. The program amounts to just setting $y$ equal to $x-1$.

Comment: @MJD Ah, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By Rule of Assignment, you have:

$\{ x > 1 \} a = 1 \{ a = 1\land x > 1\}$

and

$\{ a = 1\land x > 1 \} y = x \{ a = 1\land x > 1\land y = x\}$

and

$\{ a = 1\land x > 1\land y = x\} y = y - a \{ a = 1 \land x > 1\land y = x-1 \}$

You can now use the Rule of Composition twice to make that into:

$\{ x > 1 \} a = 1; y = x; y = y - a \{ a = 1\land x > 1\land y = x-1 \}$

which by basic logic and arithmetic means:

$\{ x > 1 \} a = 1; y = x; y = y - a \{ a = 1\land y > 0\land x > y \}$

Of course, all the interesting work is done by the 'basic logic and arithmetic' part. The Hoare logic itself is actually not doing much of interest for this 'proof' at all.

Note: This is my first time seeing Hoare Logic so just trying to make sense of this from Wikipedia ... those that  know about Hoare logic please rip this post apart if it contains mistakes!